# Active Directory DNS security and zones

Tags: security, dns, active-directory

Excuse the rather long post explaining, I hope it makes sense!

We have a bit of a debate at work as how to best secure our AD DNS schema.

Our AD is designed with the 3-tier security process with T0 being architecture (able to manage core DNS zones and other structural elements of the AD), T1 being super admins able to administer AD but not anything architectural (only T1 can for example issue certificates or delete / modify user accounts). T2 are just normal local admins obtaining local admin rights on any server but cannot change any user account info...

Anyway, we have a base DNS. Our AD DCs are in it. Let's call it contoso.com. It's a single forest, single domain setup. We have also created a few sub zones, let's say sales.contoso.com and marketing.contoso.com.

All non-Windows (Linux and other non-MS AD clients) are placed in their sub zones. DNS records are manually created to reflect their DNS location and corresponding IP address.

But all Windows clients when joined to the domain by default end up in just contoso.com. I had suggested changing their DNS zone after joining AD so they could be placed in their correct DNS zone (sales.contoso.com or marketing.contoso.com). But my colleagues have suggested "this is not supported".

The issue we have is currently, any authenticated user can add any Windows machine to the domain. When they do that, the machine ends up in contoso.com. However, only a T0 domain admin can then make any changes here, and these people aren't necessarily available. Under normal operations, ideally need to be able to manage computers, update DNS records for all normal computers and servers, but preferably without requiring the need of a T0 architecture admin.

I understand the preference to secure contoso.com as that's where the domain controllers are as well as all the DNS information (in _msdcs.contoso.com, etc). You wouldn't want anyone other than a T0 playing around in there changing things.

My suggestion would be to keep the domain controllers and root PKI/CA in contoso.com but allow all other member computers to be placed in their selective sub DNS zones.

This means that a T1 admin can then make any changes on those sub zones where they have the right to do so (but not contoso.com which remains exlucisvely under T0 control).

Is this a bad idea? Is there any reason why computers joined to the domain have to be in the root contoso.com DNS zone? Can they not be moved into a Sub zone allowing enabling delegation to local T1 admin management?

Any thoughts and experience appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict reason as far as I know; a computer's registration in DNS is not strongly bound to its AD membership (though the registration procedure is authenticated *by* its AD membership). You *can* change a computer's "Primary DNS Suffix" through its System settings at any point, and it will attempt to self-register a DNS record under whichever zone you want. It will still know which AD domain it's a member of, regardless of the DNS suffix.

(The DNS records are managed by hosts themselves via Kerberos-authenticated DNS UPDATE requests – not by your DCs.)

However, make sure the computer's SPNs on its AD account are updated accordingly (but I think Windows will do this automatically whenever you change its primary DNS suffix), as it needs to be able to acquire tickets to self (i.e. for its own FQDN) when validating interactive logins.

(Personally, I would have used "ad.contoso.com" for the AD forest, and left "contoso.com" to non-AD management.)

Comment: Thanks.
I had done that (changed the primary suffix on the newly-joined computer) in the past and it works fine. It updates DNS so they're both in sync. What I don't know is if attempting this on our current domain will work or not - maybe a T0 access level is required as you're effectively deleting the record in contoso.com which is normally protected to move / create it in sales.contoso.com (as an example).
In the previous domain where I had it set up like this (but before the Microsof tier-level security was applied), it worked find and I never noticed any side-effects.